# High rep question and answers must be protected from edit

Tags: discussion, edits, protected-questions

While reviewing **Suggested Edits** review queue, I saw that many users target the highly active (High upvotes) questions and answers.

The questions can be *protected* to avoid answers but there is no protection to edit the post.

I would like to share my thought that these questions and answers need to be protected from the low rep or new users to make an edit.

I know we already have protection for all the posts for low rep users. It goes to the review queue, but as I observed from the past few days, these users succeed in the review queue.

The review queue is not 100% accurate. In the review process, many users just accept the edit without making an effort to see the edit changes or the weight of the post. That's why it should not be allowed to make an edit.

Comment: Right, only people with more than 1M reputation should be able to edit these posts.

Comment: Untill 2k rep it will be in review queue after 2k SO trusts its users.

Comment: @yivi: Agree, but as I observed from the past few days, these users succeed in the review queue. The review process is not accurate.

Comment: When bad edits succeed, then don't forget to roll them back and to flag the post so a mod can issue a review suspension for the reviewers when appropriate.

Comment: What does it take to stop a *bad guy* with a *text editor*? A *good guy* with a *text editor*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We already have that "protection".

Edits by users with less than 2000 reputation need to be reviewed with users with at least 2000 reputation. Only users with 2000 reputation points or more [can edit any post without having their edits reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

It's even better: this "protection" applies to all posts, not only to *"highly active questions"*.

No system is perfect, and many users review incorrectly.

Reviewers are not asked (and should not be asked) to evaluate the "weight of the post". What post is being edited is mostly irrelevant, what matters is that the suggested edit is improving the post as much as possible without introducing new problems.

If you see instances of users making a string of bad reviews, please raise a flag so a moderator can take a look and maybe have word with them.

If bad edits are being approved, we should try to make it so the review queue works better, not add friction to the editing process.

Comment: The review queue is not 100% accurate. Many users just accept the edit without making an effort to see the edit changes or the weight of the post.

Comment: Yes, human are fallible, sadly. It's a shame. No system is foolproof, since they keep making better fools.

Comment: Thanks yivi. It is my suggestion to make this community better and accurate. I'm a Swift developer, today I saw that one user was doing wrong edit on extended class. And he did this kind of change on many highly upvoted answers and you know what most of his edits approved. That is why I realize to raise a flag.

Comment: It's "yi**v**i", not "yi**y**i". And remember to raise a custom flag if you see someone making a string of bad reviews. A string of bad edits it's usually a self-solving problem, since those users tend to get edit-banned, but if you see a bad editor flying under the radar, flag that as well.

Comment: @Kampai That is a bad situation, right, but only a symptom of the real issue: bad reviewers. Bad edits from anyone (below 2k) must be prevented from those reviewers, not just the ones from new or low rep users.

Comment: Let's hope that in the future SO can make it better.

Comment: @Kampai Can you show an example of such bad Swift edit?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24823350

Comment: Edit is OK. See [Class-only protocols, class vs AnyObject?](https://forums.swift.org/t/class-only-protocols-class-vs-anyobject/11507) According to Slava Pestov (compiler engineer at Apple) since Swift 4 both are equivalent and class has been effectively deprecated. Since Swift 3 is obsolete, there is no harm done in updating old answers to newer syntax. Having said that, I am not really fond of such code edits and would prefer leaving comment to the OP instead, especially when older syntax is still working (unless something is changed in newest Swift, which I haven't used yet)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: It is an example, there are many edits that are directly edited just to make it compatible with the new version but at the same time it deviates with the older version. If someone just blindly copy to and working in the older version it will give an error. As a result - downvote!!!

Comment: I know. That is why I am generally not fond of such edits. But in this case I don't think it will cause any harm.

Comment: I wish we could have more clear guidance in help center about editing code. something like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Answer (score 5):

Imagine there is a post about, let's say JavaScript. It is highly upvoted, but the information contains a little mistake. Now someone, let's say Brendan Eich, sees this wrong post, and as he definitely  *knows better* he wants to edit the post. He cannot, because according to you, he doesn't have *enough reputation*.

Comment: Well, he can add a comment below the answer.

Comment: No he cannot. You need at least 50 rep to comment.

Comment: Yes, it's a trade off. Either you can go with pure answer ( it is high repo answer, only if contains best solution) or you can allow anyone to play with it.

Comment: And for your case, Brendan Eich does not have to edit the actual post. He can add a new answer with an updated version, which is the most common case in SO.

Comment: I am not sure about the SO standards that when to post a new answer or when to make an edit. But I am just sharing my thoughts, I may wrong but this is how I feel. And thanks for sharing the example.

Comment: @kampai okay, yeah, the *outdated language feature* is not a good example. Let's say there is a little typo somewhere...

Comment: In that case I agree with you. Improvements should be possible by everyone, even anonymous users. I'm against the proposed change anyway. The issue here aren't the bad edits, but the reviewers accepting those bad edits.